# Stanford Parser - POS tagging - pronoun as noun?

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I noticed that the Stanford Parser taggs "anyone" and "anybody" as a noun, whereas they are pronouns; I tried to set "anyone" in different contexts, I got the same result. Can anyone tell me if it hapenned to him/her and if there is a way to correct it (I mean perhaps some settings ?).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a linguistics question than a code question. The analysis of these words is complex. Many linguists would describe them as being a fused determiner and noun, as they fairly transparently are at least historically.

In general we currently use the Penn Treebank standards for tokenization, part-of-speech, and phrasal labels for English. The [Penn Treebank](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC99T42) annotates these words as noun (NN) - rightly or wrongly - so that is what our tools currently do.

However, you might be pleased to know that under the [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/) guidelines, these words are indeed pronouns (PRON). We are sure to be moving towards greater use of Universal Dependencies in future releases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would like to know if you are about to release a lemmatization tool for other languages than English? For example French, Spanish, Italian, Chinese?

Comment: Hallo, I would like your advice concerning the optimisation of the parser when lemmatizing? In my case, I annotate my document (instance of Annotation) with properties, then I iterate on its sentences (one sentence is a CoreMap type object) and for each sentence on its tokens (CoreLabel type object), the I get the lemma using CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation. The process is extremely long. Can you provide advice for optimisation? Thank you.